# Show that $\lim{\sup{A}}$ is the supremum of all limit points of $A$

Tags: calculus

**Definition.** Let $A$ be a nonempty subset of $\mathbb{R}$. $x \in \mathbb{R}$ is called an *almost upper bound* of $A$ if there are only finitely many $y \in A$ for which $y \geq x$. Similarly we define almost lower bounds. Define $\lim \sup{A}$ to be the infimum of all almost upper bounds of $A$ and $\lim \inf{A}$ to be the supremum of all almost lower bounds of $A$.

> Show that $\lim{\sup{A}}$ is the supremum of all limit points of $A$ and $\lim{\inf{A}}$ is the infimum of all limit points of $A$.

I don't see how we can from the definition of an almost upper bound of $A$ and the definition of $\lim{\sup{A}}$ to the fact that $\lim{\sup{A}}$is the supremum of all limit points of $A$. Similarly with the almost lower bound.

Comment: For instance, if $A=[0,1]\cup \{2\}$, then $[1,2]$ are the almost upper bounds. Thus $\limsup A=1$. The limit points of $A$ are $[0,1]$, and $1$ is the supremum of those. The connection is that $x$ cannot be an almost upper bound if there is a limit point $a\in A$ with $x<a$.

Comment: @Arthur There are more upper bounds to $A$ than just $[1,2]$.

Comment: Yes, it's supposed to be $[1,\infty)$.

Comment: I think this answer (http://math.stackexchange.com/a/1802335/72031) to your previous question suffices. I have established that $\limsup A$ is in fact the largest limit point of $A$.

Answer (score 1):

Assume that $A$ has limit points and is bounded above. To show that $\limsup A$ is the same as the supremum of the limit points of $A$, let $x\in \Bbb R$ be the supremum of the limit points of $A$. You need to show

1. If we have $y\in \Bbb R$ with $y<x$, then $y$ is not an almost upper bound of $A$.
2. If we have $y\in \Bbb R$ with $x<y$, then there is an almost upper bound $z$ of $A$ with $z<y$.

These two together will make $x$ the infimum of the almost upper bounds of $A$, which by definition is $\limsup A$.